# Adding items to specific places in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=len(sorted_list)
z=1
for y in range (2,x):
    if sorted_list[y][1]=="0" and len(sorted_list[y])>3:
        z+=1
        sorted_list.insert(y,'Message '+ str(z))
        x+=1
    else:
        continue
```

I have a list named "sorted_list". I want to add some items to list but i have a problem. When i try this code it goes to infinity. I want to group numbers by 0th index. I have an input like that:

```
[['65', '0', 'Hello'],
['65', '1', 'world'],
['78', '0', "what's"],
['78', '1', 'up']]
```

I want the output like that:

```
Message 1
65 0 Hello 
65 1 world
Message 2
78 0 what's
78 1 up
```

Comment: This code doesn't go to infinity, but it doesn't do anything either because none of the list items are `"0"`.

Comment: I made a mistake while uploading the question i updated it. @Samwise

Answer (score 1):

In general it's not a great idea to try to modify a list as you're iterating over it, because it's very easy to confuse yourself.  Since you just want to print the list contents with extra messages interspersed, I think it's better to just not modify the list and print the messages as you iterate.

The easy way to group things according to specific criteria (in this case the 0th index of each list) is to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for i, (_, group) in enumerate(groupby(sorted_list, lambda i: i[0])):
...     print(f"Message {i+1}")
...     for line in group:
...         print(" ".join(line))
...
Message 1
65 1 Hello
65 2 world
Message 2
78 2 what's
78 3 up
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, thank you so much but if i want to do that in list method how could i, because i am a student and i haven't learnt the groupby so i couldn't understand correctly. But thanks!

Comment: It's easier to learn how to use `groupby` than to rewrite it yourself.  :)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby  The documentation does include source for a sample implementation if you want to understand exactly how it works!  All it's doing is grouping things together that are "the same" according to the key function you pass it (in this case `lambda i: i[0]` which just gets the 0th element of each thing).

Comment: Thanks again,when  i want to put this to an output file it didn't work.

Comment: There's nothing I can really do to debug if the only information is "it didn't work", but I have every confidence you'll be able to figure it out!  :)

Comment: I figured :) I am so glad for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

sorted_list = [['65', '0', 'Hello'],
['65', '1', 'world'],
['78', '0', "what's"],
['78', '1', 'up']]

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_list)
groups = df.groupby(0) #group by first column

for i,(name, group) in enumerate(groups):
  print('Message {0}'.format(i+1))
  for c1, c2, c3 in group.to_numpy():
    print(c1,c2,c3)
```